# Affine transform with interpolation

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, interpolation

I would like to do an affine transformation on a very low resolution bitmap and I would like to do it while preserving the maximum amount of information.

My input data is a 1 bit 64-by-64 pixel image of hand written character and my output would be greyscale and higher resolution. Upon analysing the image I construct a series of affine transformations (rotation, scaling, shear, translation) what I could multiply into a single affine transformation matrix.

My problem is that given the **input image** and my computed **affine transformation matrix**, how can I calculate my output image in the highest possible quality? I have read articles about different interpolation techniques, but all of them are about how to do interpolation for scaling, and not for general affine transforms.

Here is a demo what is doing exactly what I am looking for. Given an affine transformation matrix and an interpolation technique it calculates an image.

http://bigwww.epfl.ch/demo/jaffine/index.html

**Can you explain me what are the steps required for calculating a higher resolution (for example 4x) greyscale image, if I have a lower resolution 1-bit input and a given T affine transformation matrix?**

Can you link me to some ***source code*** or ***tutorials*** or ***articles*** or possibly even ***books*** about how to implement a linear, cubic or better interpolation with affine transform?

I need to implement this problem in Java, and I know Java has an Affine class, but I don't know if it implements interpolation. Do you know any C++ or Java library what has nice to read code for figuring out how to write an algorithm for doing affine transform using interpolation?

**Are there any freely available libraries for Java or C++ which have built-in functions for calculating affine transform using interpolation?**

Comment: You can do affine transforms with anti-aliasing in java with the java2d api

Comment: Have you considered using SVG images which scale much nicer than standard bitmap images? Apache's [Batik library](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) works with Java and can handle this for you I believe.

Comment: @sibbo: that helps with Shapes, but won't help for bitmapped images.

Comment: you can transform images, too

Comment: @Sibbo: I know that you can transform images, but just what effect do you think anti-aliasing rendering hints will have on bitmapped images? I'll give you a hint: ***none***. There are other rendering hints that may help some, but still you're left with the ambiguities of bitmapped data being expanded to a larger size, exposing their limits of resolution.

Comment: zsero: please have a look here at a decent explanation of various types of interpolations available when you transform a bitmap: [Geometric Image Manipulation](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Geom-image-manip.doc.html). Check out section 8.2 in particular. Based on this, have you tried setting RenderingHints to use one of the Bicubic interpolation types such as INTERP_BICUBIC or INTERP_BICUBIC2?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that the Java implementation has bicubic! I will have a look at it!

Comment: There was an amazing paper from Microsoft Research for converting pixel art into vector graphics, in case you are interested in new developments: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the solution I ended up with.

1. I transformed all my array[][] into a BufferedImage object

   ```
   static BufferedImage BImageFrom2DArray(float data[][]) {
       int width = data.length;
       int height = data[0].length;
       BufferedImage myimage = new BufferedImage(width, height,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
           for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
               int value = (int) ((1f - data[x][y]) * 255f);
               myimage.setRGB(y, x, (value << 16) | (value << 8) | value);
           }
       }
       return myimage;
   }
   ```
2. Applied the affine transformation using AffineTransformOp with interpolation bicubic

   ```
       AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC);
       BufferedImage im_transformed = op.filter(im_src, null);
   ```
3. Transformed back the BufferedImage object into array[][]:

   ```
       static float[][] ArrayFromBImage(BufferedImage bimage, int width, int height) {
       int max_x = bimage.getWidth();
       int max_y = bimage.getHeight();
       float[][] array = new float[width][height];
       for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
           for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
               float red, alpha, value;
               int color;
               if (x >= max_x || y >= max_y) {
                   array[y][x] = 0;
               } else {
                   color = bimage.getRGB(x, y);
                   alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
                   red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
                   value = 1f - red / 255;
                   if (alpha == 0) {
                       array[y][x] = 0;
                   } else {
                       array[y][x] = value;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return array;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The same people you linked to have a C implementation with several interpolation options [here](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/affine/). You could probably use JNI to wrap it. There is also [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/), which wraps OpenCV. OpenCV contains the warpAffine, which has interpolation. Also, check out the [Java Advanced Imaging](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) API [here](http://java.net/projects/jai/).