# Ugly diagonal lines after affine transform

Tags: java, awt, rendering, antialiasing, affinetransform

I'm working on figures drawing on low-end device. I noticed that after scale affine transformation many of thin lines (e.g. `1px` width) become ugly. Especially in case of diagonal lines (e.g. a line that's sloped by 45 degrees).

I prepared demo program with the most evident examples (I included boilerplate GUI code so you can run the example):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class DiagonalLinesDemo extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);

        drawRemark(graphics, 1F, 20);
        drawDiagonalLine(graphics, 1F, 0);

        drawRemark(graphics, 1.1070F, 80);
        drawDiagonalLine(graphics, 1.1070F, 60);

        drawRemark(graphics, 1.0162F, 160);
        drawDiagonalLine(graphics, 1.0162F, 140);

        drawRemark(graphics, 1.3300F, 250);
        drawDiagonalLine(graphics, 1.3300F, 160);

        drawRemark(graphics, 1.5555F, 330);
        drawDiagonalLine(graphics, 1.5555F, 180);
    }

    private static void drawDiagonalLine(Graphics2D graphics, float scale, int anchor)
    {
        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD);
        path.moveTo(anchor + 10, 100);
        path.lineTo(anchor + 60, 50);

        AffineTransform upScaleTransform = new AffineTransform(
                scale,
                0F,
                0F,
                scale,
                0F,
                0F);

        graphics.setTransform(upScaleTransform);

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.draw(path);
    }

    private static void drawRemark(Graphics2D graphics, float scale, int anchor)
    {
        graphics.setTransform(new AffineTransform());
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        String remark = String.format("%1.4f", scale);
        graphics.drawString(remark, anchor, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Diagonal Lines Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

        DiagonalLinesDemo panel = new DiagonalLinesDemo();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = PANEL_WIDTH + 50;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = PANEL_HEIGHT + 50;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, after transformation (scale values are remarked above the lines for clarity) ugly fractures appeared. I know that fractures are unavoidable due to absence of antialiasing (**I cannot enable antialiasing** due to customer's limitations). But I expect more-or-less pretty result, like it's depicted below (I highlighted desired shapes in red):

[image]

I tried to adjust winding rule, rendering hints. But without luck. Also, I'm aware of [interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862583/affine-transform-with-interpolation). But that approach is too resource-consuming (as I said earlier, customer's hardware resources are very limited). Are there any other options?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I've published full version of the demo.